# Cannot save NSArray of double to file ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io, nsarray, plist

I am using the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829631/is-it-possible-to-save-nsmutablearray-or-nsdictionary-data-as-file-in-ios) question to save an `NSArray` to a file.  I can't retrieve the array though.  I am getting `0x00000000` for my retrieved `boundaries` array when I do the following:

to save:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"boundaries"];

[array writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

to retrieve:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"boundaries"];

NSArray *boundaries = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Is something wrong with this?  The array is full of correct data when I save it.

I tried saving `[myArray description]` and I saved it and retrieved it okay, but the data is obviously different than what I want to have.  I'm saving 8 doubles in the array.

Comment: Go to the app's sandbox and check whether you are able to save file correctly or not.

Comment: How do you know that the file has been written successfully?  You're not checking the return value from the write.  Also, as enricmacias says in his answer, you are writing a variable called `array`  Are you sure it's got anything in it?

Comment: Did I say I knew it was written correctly?  I just said that the array is filled with 8 doubles...  I know because I set a break point.. and did `po array' and it gave me 8 doubles.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"boundaries"];

[array writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Where is this 'array' variable coming from?

Anyway you won't we able to save doubles directly into a NSArray. You need to save those doubles as NSNumber. Like this:

```
[[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:doubleNumber];
```

Comment: I don't want to show the entire method that shows how I retrieve data from the database and set the array with that data.  That's why I just put in "array" and said that the array is filled with 8 doubles...  If you want to see that I sure can put it up there.

Comment: It's ok. Just make sure the information in that array is correct. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010363/nsarray-writetofile-fails It seems NSNumber are not valid values for writeToFile: Try saving NSString instead of NSNumber

Answer (score 1):

Get the data of the array using

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
```

and then save it in your documents directory. To Retrieve it back,

```
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

This should work.

Comment: so should the method used in the question.