# Swift Data File not being created

Tags: swift, file

I am trying to save an array of a user-created class named "TopTenData".  The code I used follows.  Running the code indicates the file is created, but the file is NOT created. When I navigate to the path I do not find the desired file.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
func writeArrayToPlist(array: [TopTenData]) {
    if let arrayPath: String = createArrayPath() {
        (array as NSArray).writeToFile(arrayPath, atomically: false)
        print("Array written successfully")   
        print(arrayPath)   // navigating this path shows no files
    }
}

func createArrayPath () -> String? {
    if let docsPath: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true).last {
        return ((docsPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("myTopTenData") as NSString).stringByAppendingPathExtension("plist")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSArray writeToFile fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010363/nsarray-writetofile-fails)

Answer (score 0):

writeToFile method of NSArray has some limitations. For example it only support these data types:

- NSString
- NSData
- NSDate
- NSNumber
- NSArray
- NSDictionary

For custom data types you can use **NSKeyedArchiver** and **NSKeyedUnarchiver**

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010363/nsarray-writetofile-fails)

Comment: Thanks, you steered me in the correct direction.  I found this demo from Apple to be very helpful.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson10.html

Comment: If this solves your problem then please mark it as correct. Thank you.